# Help with proof of Inverse-Function Theorem in $ \mathbb R ^ n $

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

> Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$, and let $f: U \to \mathbb{R^n}$ be a $C^1$ function such that, for all $x$ $\in$ $U$, $Df(x)$ is an isomorphism.

My goal is to show if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ has an $C^1$ inverse function. I also showed that $f(U)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ but I can't find a way to verify that $f^{-1}$ will exist and be $C^1$ function. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $f$ is injective, then $f:U\rightarrow f(U)$ is bijective and hence $f^{-1}$ is well-defined. By the inverse function theorem you have around every point $x_0\in U$ an inverse function which is $C^1$. However, by the uniqueness part of the inverse function theorem this local inverse must coimcide with $f^{-1}$ around $f(x_0)$. Thus, $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$ around $f(x_0)$. Now use the fact that this holds true for all $x_0\in U$ to conclude.

Comment: I edited the title to make it more informative, and I called it a proof of the IVT, since this statement is a form of that theorem and you had that in your tags; but maybe you want to call it a proof of a corollary of the IVT (a more basic form of which Severin uses in his proof).